# Append in a table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

This is my code to add rows to a table

```
for(var i=0;i<subjects.length;i++){
    $('#table-wrapper table').append("<tr><td data-subjectid="+i+">"+subjects[i].name+"</td>");
    for(var j=0;j<no_of_batches;j++){
            $('#table-wrapper table').append("<td data-batchid="+j+"></td>");
    }
    $('#table-wrapper table').append("</tr>");
}
```

The output this produces is

```
<table> 
    <tbody>
       <tr>
         <tr>
           <td data-subjectid="2">DBMS</td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
        <td data-batchid="0"></td>
        <td data-batchid="1"></td>
        <td data-batchid="2"></td>
        <td data-batchid="3"></td>
 </table>
```

Why aren't the inner `<td>`'s getting appended to the `<tr>` tag at the end of the table but instead out of the `<tbody>`

Comment: Append elements, not partial HTML.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a string at the top, adding everything to it, and then appending it at the bottom of the `for`.

Comment: @Carl Saldanha, do you want to the <td> with data-subjectid to be on top of the other td's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending to the table by

```
$('#table-wrapper table').append("<td data-batchid="+j+"></td>");
```

need to append to the last tr

```
$('#table-wrapper table tr:last-child').append("<td data-batchid="+j+"></td>");
```

have not tested but it should work

The better way is to add the contents to a string then append once

```
var temp;
for(var i=0;i<subjects.length;i++){
    temp = "<tr><td data-subjectid="+i+">"+subjects[i].name+"</td>";
    for(var j=0;j<no_of_batches;j++){
            temp = temp + "<td data-batchid="+j+"></td>";
    }
    temp = temp + "</tr>"
}
$('#table-wrapper table tbody').append(temp);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this -

```
for(var i=0;i<subjects.length;i++){
    var $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
    $tr.append("<td data-subjectid="+i+">"+subjects[i].name+"</td>");
    for(var j=0;j<no_of_batches;j++){
            $tr.append("<td data-batchid="+j+"></td>");
    }
    $('#table-wrapper table').append($tr);
}
```

Comment: This is beautiful answer because of how clear it is to set  $('<tr></tr>') as our base point to work from.  Once we define where to append or prepend from, the complications just melt away. Nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code right, you might try this way:

```
var table = $('#table-wrapper table');
for(var i = 0; i < subjects.length; i++) {
    var row = $('<tr />');
    row.append("<td data-subjectid=" + i + ">" + subjects[i].name + "</td>");
    for(var j = 0; j < no_of_batches; j++) {
        row.append("<td data-batchid=" + j + "></td>");
    }
    table.append(row);
}
```

There you create a row, append cells to it and after it append new row to the table.
You might want cache the reference to your table as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `append` method is not a `writeln` equivalent. It actually tries to parce the text and produce final complete tags.

Use a temporary string variable to accumulate all the stuff you want to append, and call `append` only once at the end.

```
var s;
for(var i=0;i<subjects.length;i++){
  s = "<tr><td data-subjectid="+i+">"+subjects[i].name+"</td>";
  for(var j=0;j<no_of_batches;j++){
    s += "<td data-batchid="+j+"></td>";
  }
  s += "</tr>";
  $('#table-wrapper table').append(s);
}
```

Comment: There is a tbody element inside the table element. This would work if the last line was changed to $('#table-wrapper table tbody').append(s);